# Changing multiple column names

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame with such column names:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

And I would like to change names from 'c' to 'f' (actually add string to the name of column), so the whole data frame column names would look like this:

```
['a','b','var_c_equal','var_d_equal','var_e_equal','var_f_equal','g']
```

Well, firstly I made a function that changes column names with the string i want:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'or_'+x+'_no', inplace=True)
```

But now I really want to understand how to implement something like this:

```
df.loc[:,'c':'f'].rename(columns=lambda x: 'var_'+x+'_equal', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a dictionary instead of an anonymous function. Both the below variations assume the columns you need to rename are contiguous.

**Contiguous columns by position**

```
d = {k: 'var_'+k+'_equal' for k in df.columns[2:6]}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
```

**Contiguous columns by name**

If you need to calculate the numerical indices:

```
cols = df.columns.get_loc
d = {k: 'var_'+k+'_equal' for k in df.columns[cols('c'):cols('f')+1]}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
```

**Specifically identified columns**

If you want to provide the columns explicitly:

```
d = {k: 'var_'+k+'_equal' for k in 'cdef'}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
```

Comment: I am interested in first variant, but how can i select range by column names, but not indexes.

Comment: My second solution deals with column names, you input 'c' & 'f' and all columns between them will be renamed.

Comment: oh sorry. Thank you a lot for your help)

Answer (score 3):

You can a use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that like:

#### Code:

```
new_columns = ['var_{}_equal'.format(c) if c in 'cdef' else c for c in columns]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2), 'b':(1,2), 'c':(1,2), 'd':(1,2)})
print(df)
df.columns = ['var_{}_equal'.format(c) if c in 'cdef' else c
               for c in df.columns]
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2

   a  b  var_c_equal  var_d_equal
0  1  1            1            1
1  2  2            2            2
```